# JSFiddle and Canvas // What is up?

Tags: html5-canvas, jsfiddle

I set up this simple Koch fractal JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oana/kU5D8/9/ -

But no dice.

The code comes from Keith Peters's Playing with Chaos.

The code does work locally. Locally, it is organized like so: the HTML file explicitly references 2 .js files. The first one, chaos.js, contains the assignment of the variable chaos. The second, koch.js, contains the function expression assigned to window.onload.

This is more of a JSFiddle exercise for me. How do I begin debugging why I am seeing nada in the JSFiddle?

Thank you kindly!

PS: stackoverflow tells me links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code so here is the code -

```
var chaos = (function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            this.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        },

        setSize: function (width, height) {
            this.width = this.canvas.width = width;
            this.height = this.canvas.height = height;

        },

        clear: function () {
            if (color) {
                this.context.fillStyle = color;
                this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            } else {
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

            }
        }


    };

}());


window.onload = function () {
    var maxDepth = 0;

    init();

    function init() {
        chaos.init();
        draw();
        document.body.addEventListener('keyup',

        function (event) {
            console.log(event.keyCode);
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 32:
                    maxDepth += 1;
                    draw();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

    }

    function draw() {
        var p0 = {
            x: chaos.width * 0.1,
            y: chaos.height * 0.75

        };

        var p1 = {
            x: chaos.width * 0.9,
            y: chaos.height * 0.75
        };

        chaos.clear();
        chaos.context.lineWidth = 2;

        koch(p0, p1, maxDepth);

    }

    function koch(p0, p1, depth) {
        var dx = p1.x - p0.x,
            dy = p1.y - p0.y,
            dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
        unit = dist / 3,
        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx), pa, pb, pc;

        pa = {
            x: p0.x + Math.cos(angle) * unit,
            y: p0.y + Math.sin(angle) * unit
        };


        pb = {
            x: pa.x + Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 3) * unit,
            y: pa.y + Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 3) * unit
        };

        pc = {
            x: p0.x + Math.cos(angle) * unit * 2,
            y: p0.y + Math.sin(angle) * unit * 2
        };

        if (depth === 0) {
            chaos.context.beginPath();
            chaos.context.moveTo(p0.x, p0.y);
            chaos.context.lineTo(pa.x, pa.y);
            chaos.context.lineTo(pb.x, pb.y);
            chaos.context.lineTo(pc.x, pc.y);
            chaos.context.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
            chaos.context.stroke();

        } else {
            koch(p0, pa, depth - 1);
            koch(pa, pb, depth - 1);
            koch(pb, pc, depth - 1);
            koch(pc, p1, depth - 1);

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off - you don't need to specify `head` and `body` tags with jsFiddle. The div doesn't have a function either in this case.

You can select to insert your code in body (or header) if you want to use `onload` manually (as `onload` on window won't trigger as the default on jsFiddle is to trigger the script on this event):

[image]

The `color` variable is missing from the code. You open console in the browser (I use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> in FF and Chrome) and you can see typical errors there.

[image]

That is this line (I usually right click the result frame to see the source - if someone has a better way to find the line number please comment):

```
...
clear: function () {
    if (color) {
...
```

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/kU5D8/12/)**

But not all errors are caught this way. You can freely add for example properties to typical objects (for example due to typos) without the parser complaining.

Comment: Ken, is that the fiddle you meant to link to? I am not able to see the Koch curve/snowflake - were you? I see we're still hooking into window's onload.

Comment: Actually, passing color as argument to the function fixed it !! It was a matter of fixing the color error. I kept everything else the same, including hooking onto the window.onload event. Thanks, Ken, for pointing out the color issue !